# ALTER DATABASE / ADD FILE / VARIABLE FILENAME?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to add a file/file group to an existing database, but I need to get the path from a variable because it will be different when this script is finalized. When I check the script in SQL Management Studio 2008 R2, it returns an error at `FILENAME = @Path`.

How can I use that variable?

SCRIPT WILL NOT BE RUN FROM THE COMMAND LINE!

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB]
ADD FILEGROUP [MyDB_FileStream] CONTAINS FILESTREAM
GO

DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Path = 'C:\whatEverIWantItToBe\ThisCouldChangeWithLogic\YouGetThePoint\'

ALTER DATABASE [MyDB]
ADD FILE
  (NAME = 'MyDB_FileStream'
   , FILENAME = @Path
   )
TO FILEGROUP [MyDB_FileStream]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using dynamic SQL:

```
Declare @Path nvarchar(max)
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)

Set @Path = 'C:\whatEverIWantItToBe\ThisCouldChangeWithLogic\YouGetThePoint\'

Set @Sql = 'Alter Database [MyDb]
    Add File( Name = ''MyDb_FileStream''
            , FileName = ' + QuoteName( @Path, '''' ) 
            + ') To FileGroup [MyDbFileStream]'

Exec( @Sql )
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT!!! I always hated dynamic SQL because it seemed to me it "escaped" parse checking for errors...but maybe it has its uses

Comment: Just make sure @Path is coming from a trusted source, and not Little Bobby Tables http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @SqlACID - What could you pass into the @Path variable that would cause the execution of a statement you did not want? The problem will come when you try to execute the stored proc (presumably since we're using a variable) from the client-side not from within the proc itself. Assuming the call to the stored proc call is parameterized, what could be passed into @Path that wouldn't be escaped or error?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that will work for you but if you're going to run the script from a command line you could do:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB]
ADD FILE (NAME = 'MyDB_FileStream', FILENAME = $(path))
TO FILEGROUP [MyDB_FileStream]
```

And run it with:

```
sqlcmd -s servername -i script.sql -v path="path to the file"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but usually dynamic sql can help to solve this kind problem