# How to use varchar variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I try to use `varchar` string declared as variable:

```
DECLARE @fsPath AS varchar = 'D:\win-develop\FSCat';
```

But in usage:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb
ADD FILE
( NAME = 'FSCatalog', FILENAME = @fsPath
)
TO FILEGROUP MyDbFSGroup;
GO
```

I got error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@fsPath'.
```

What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying the length and the default length is "1" in this context.  So:

```
DECLARE @fsPath AS varchar(max) = 'D:\win-develop\FSCat';
```

However, that is only one problem.  You are not permitted to use variables in `alter database`.  SQL Server documentation is rather convoluted on this topic, but you can always use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
ALTER DATABASE MyDb
ADD FILE( NAME = ''FSCatalog'', FILENAME = ''@fsPath'')
TO FILEGROUP MyDbFSGroup';

select @sql = replace(@sql, '@fspath', @fsPath);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Gordon: please edit your answer to use ''FSCatalog'' instead of one single quote

Answer (score 3):

You need to use dynamic SQL in-order to achieve this.
We cannot pass variables to ALTER

Check out [ALTER DATABASE / ADD FILE / VARIABLE FILENAME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590448/alter-database-add-file-variable-filename)

Answer (score 1):

Just `varchar` added the value : `D` in table.

`varchar(50)` added the value : `D:\win-develop\FSCat` in table.

> Specify the length !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables directly in ALTER Database. Use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE MyDb ADD FILE ( NAME = ''FSCatalog'', FILENAME = ' + @fsPath + ') TO FILEGROUP MyDbFSGroup; GO'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: With your example i got error: `Incorrect syntax near 'D:'.
`

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out, you have not specified a length for the varchar... Gordon's answer is a more complete one. You have two errors in the script.