# Use variable in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a file group with filestream as follows:

```
declare @filepath varchar(800)
set @filepath = convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')) + N'MyDb_Files.ndf' 
print @filepath

alter database MyDb add file (name = 'MyDb_Files', filename = filepath) to filegroup MyDb_Files;
go
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
The path 'filepath' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files.
```

But if I replace

```
filename = filepath
```

by

```
filename = "[Output I get from print @filepath]"
```

Then it works fine ... So using the variable seems to be a problem.

Why?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(800)
set @sql = 
'
declare @filepath nvarchar(800)
set @filepath = concat(convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY("InstanceDefaultDataPath")), "MyDb.ndf")     
alter database MyDb add file (name = "MyDb_Files", filename = @filepath to filegroup MyDb_Files;        
'
exec (@sql)
```

But I keep getting the error:
Incorrect syntax near '@filepath'.

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `filename = @filepath` ?

Comment: When I use that I get the error "incorrect sintax near filepath. Expecting Id, integer, string or text_lex ... How to fix this?

Comment: Ah... then try something along the lines of `set @strSql = '<your complete alter statement>'` followed by `EXEC @strSql` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ALTER DATABASE / ADD FILE / VARIABLE FILENAME?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590448/alter-database-add-file-variable-filename)

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to use a parameter (@filepath) on a DDL statement that doesn’t allow such construct; the filename argument in the DDL accepts literals.
Copied from (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx):

```
<filespec>::= 
(
NAME = logical_file_name  
[ , NEWNAME = new_logical_name ] 
[ , FILENAME = {'os_file_name' | 'filestream_path' | 'memory_optimized_data_path' } ] 
[ , SIZE = size [ KB | MB | GB | TB ] ] 
[ , MAXSIZE = { max_size [ KB | MB | GB | TB ] | UNLIMITED } ] 
[ , FILEGROWTH = growth_increment [ KB | MB | GB | TB| % ] ] 
[ , OFFLINE ]
)
```

You will have to use dynamic SQL and make sure you protect yourself against SQLi, for example:

```
declare @filepath nvarchar(800)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @filepath = concat(convert(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')), 'MyDb.ndf')     
set @sql = N'
alter database MyDb add file (name = "MyDb_Files", filename = '''+ replace(@filepath, '''', '''''') + N''') to filegroup MyDb_Files;        
'
EXEC (@sql)
```

I talk more about this topic on an old blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection/  , under the section “When parameterization is not an option”. Hopefully you will find this information useful.